# docker - passing file name as arguments to nodejs application

Tags: node.js, docker, kubernetes, arguments, openshift

I have to convert an existing `nodejs` application to run on the RedHat OpenShift container platform. Currently, the application is run as follows:

```
node index.js $HOME/arg1.json $HOME/arg2.json
```

Using files for arguments is **important** for this application since the number of arguments are quite large.

How can I ensure that the container version is also run off of the configuration files?

Comment: What you mean by "ensure that the container version is also run off of the configuration files"?

Comment: The arguments to the application are two files. How do I package my application as a Docker image so that a user can run the image with whatever file he prefers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention in your first comment the requirement that filenames be specified at runtime. Something like this will work:

```
ENV work /app
WORKDIR $work
COPY ./arg1.json ./arg2.json $work/

CMD["node", "index.js", "./arg1.json", "arg2.json"]
```

Runtime command:

```
docker run -v $(pwd)/myarg1.json:/app/arg1.json -v $(pwd)/myarg2.json:/app/arg2.json <image>
```

Comment: Thanks, I will explore this. Any OpenShift specific considerations that can be taken here?

Comment: Is the `-v` overriding the `/app/arg1.json` with the file on host `$(pwd)/myarg1.json`?

Comment: @cogitoergosum I haven't worked with OpenShift at all. Sorry, I'm no help there. 
Yes, the first part before the : is on the host, and the second part is where that will be mapped to inside the container.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the help of ENV, build the Dockerfile with some default ENV then if you need to overide with some other file, overide them at run time.

```
FROM node:alpine
ENV HOME="/app"
ENV file1="file1"
ENV file2="file2"
COPY index.js $HOME/index.js
CMD ["/bin/sh", "-c", "node $HOME/index.js $HOME/$file1 $HOME/$file2"]
```

index.js

```
const args = process.argv;
console.log(args);
```

output of nodejs script

```
[ '/usr/local/bin/node', '/app/index.js', '/app/file1', '/app/file2' ]
```

To overide filename for different config

```
docker run --rm -it -e file1="stage.json" abc
```

Now the output will be

```
[
  '/usr/local/bin/node',
  '/app/index.js',
  '/app/stage.json',
  '/app/file2'
]
```

If you are expecting big number of argument then better follow this method.

```
FROM node:alpine
ENV HOME="/app"
COPY index.js $HOME/index.js
RUN echo $'#!/bin/sh \n\
     node $HOME/index.js $@' >> /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

So now pass as many argument as you want, docker run

```
docker run --rm -it -e file1="stage.json" abc "$HOME/arg1.json $HOME/arg2.json $HOME/arg3.json"
```

node args result will be

```
[
  '/usr/local/bin/node',
  '/app/index.js',
  '/home/adiii/arg1.json',
  '/home/adiii/arg2.json',
  '/home/adiii/arg3.json'
]
```

Comment: Thanks, I will explore this. Any OpenShift specific considerations that can be taken here? Also, what is `abc` in all examples above?

Comment: Abc is image name, sorry for weird name

Comment: no `\n\` add new line. you can keep them in entrypoint if the OS has an issue ceate file entrypoint ```#!/bin/sh 
     node $HOME/index.js $@' ``` and copy entrypoint instead of inside Dockerfile

Comment: ```copy entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh``` instead of inside dockerfile

Comment: Your solution certainly echoes the file name passed as arguments. But, does it allow the container to *read* the file-system "outside" of it? That is, can the container read e.g. `/home/adiii/arg1.json`?

Comment: No, yes its pick `$HOST` from the host os, so better to the pull path to avoide picking ENV from host